# C# pinvoke structs with union and arrays

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke, unions

im failing to define the correct C# code to work with a C++ library which defines a complex struct with union and arrays, i keep getting some memory exception while executing the C++ code, and im pretty sure its due to this.

The c++ struct is as follows, ignoring enums and other struct definition (i will post them if needed but they are pretty extense)

```
typedef struct
{
DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE  eEventCode;
DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_TYPE  eEventType;
int         iTime;
int         iHandle;
unsigned char       uchAddress;
DG_CCTALK_BILL_INFO sBillInfo;
int         iBillAmount;
union
{
    long        lData;
    int     iData;
    unsigned char   ucArray[128];
    char        *cString;
    void        *pvoid;
} uData;
void            *_private;  // for use by cctalk app layer
} DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT, *PDG_CCTALK_APP_EVT;
```

And the C# code is this:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Anonymous_92d21a81_2a8b_42f4_af32_f7606aa9cf40
    {
        //deberian llevar todos 0, pero el array genera problemas al ponerle 0, y cambiandolo explota en otro lado...

        /// int
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
        public int lData;

        /// int
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
        public int iData;

        /// unsigned char[128]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128, ArraySubType = System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(4)]
        public byte[] ucArray;

        /// char*
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
        public System.IntPtr cString;

        /// void*
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
        public System.IntPtr pvoid;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT
    {

        /// DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE->_DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE
        public DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE eEventCode;

        /// DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_TYPE->_DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_TYPE
        public DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_TYPE eEventType;

        /// int
        public int iTime;

        /// int
        public int iHandle;

        /// unsigned char
        public byte uchAddress;

        /// DG_CCTALK_BILL_INFO->_DG_CCTALK_BILL_INFO
        public DG_CCTALK_BILL_INFO sBillInfo;

        /// int
        public int iBillAmount;

        /// Anonymous_92d21a81_2a8b_42f4_af32_f7606aa9cf40
        public Anonymous_92d21a81_2a8b_42f4_af32_f7606aa9cf40 uData;

        /// void*
        public System.IntPtr _private;
    }
```

Delegates and a function import

```
public delegate void DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_HANDLER(ref DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT pEVT);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("cctalk.dll", EntryPoint = "cctalk_app_enable_device", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int cctalk_app_enable_device(ref DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT param0);
```

UPDATE: new code after an asnwer, still not working:
The error is: "Attempt to read or write Protected Memory This is often an indicating that other memory is corrupt"

What is weird, is that i can use the struct on the first event call, i print all fields and they seem to be right (lData and iData have the same values, cData has a string I sent) but after the event ends the program dies. Seems like my C# code is breaking the struct or something...

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT
    {

        /// DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE->_DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE
        public DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE eEventCode;

        /// DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_TYPE->_DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_TYPE
        public DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_TYPE eEventType;

        /// int
        public int iTime;

        /// int
        public int iHandle;

        /// unsigned char
        public byte uchAddress;

        /// DG_CCTALK_BILL_INFO->_DG_CCTALK_BILL_INFO
        public DG_CCTALK_BILL_INFO sBillInfo;

        /// int            
        public int iBillAmount;            

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
        public byte[] uData;

        #region setters y getters para mapeo

        public int lData
        {
            set
            {
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), uData, sizeof(int));
            }
            get
            {
                return BitConverter.ToInt32(uData, 0);
            }
        }

        public int iData
        {
            set
            {
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), uData, sizeof(int));
            }
            get
            {
                return BitConverter.ToInt32(uData, 0);
            }
        }

        public byte[] ucArray
        {
            set
            {
                Array.Copy(value, uData, 128);
            }
            get
            {
                return uData;

            }
        }

        public IntPtr cString
        {
            set
            {
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value.ToInt32()), uData, 32);
            }
            get
            {
                return (IntPtr)BitConverter.ToInt32(uData, 0);
            }
        }

        public IntPtr pvoid
        {
            set
            {
                Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value.ToInt32()), uData, 32);
            }
            get
            {
                return (IntPtr)BitConverter.ToInt32(uData, 0);
            }
        }


        #endregion

        /// void*
        public System.IntPtr _private;
    }
```

C++ declarations:

```
typedef void (*DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_HANDLER)(PDG_CCTALK_APP_EVT pEVT);

DGCCTALK_PREFIX DG_ERROR cctalk_app_init(DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_HANDLER pfnHandler);
DGCCTALK_PREFIX DG_ERROR cctalk_app_add_link(char *szPortName);
```

Note dad DGCCTALK_PREFIX is defined as __declspec(dllexport)

C# code for those:

```
public delegate void DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_HANDLER(ref DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT pEVT);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("cctalk.dll", EntryPoint =     "cctalk_app_init", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern int cctalk_app_init(DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_HANDLER pfnHandler);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("cctalk.dll", EntryPoint = "cctalk_app_add_link", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int cctalk_app_add_link(System.IntPtr szPortName);
```

C# code invoking them

```
var handler = new DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_HANDLER(this._handler);
var resultado = cctalk_app_init(handler);
cctalk_app_add_link(Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("port=" + port));
```

C# handler header

```
private void _handler(ref DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT pEVT)
```

Comment: Why use offset of 4? And what is the error? How do you call the function?

Comment: It was originally 0, but that would cause invalid aling exception. I dont have the error here, but it was about accessing memory which the program didnt have read/write permision.

Comment: Also i dont explicitly call a method with this struct, it is actually an event fired from the c++ library, which sends me this struct ( no error here), but after the event completes, as the c++ code runs again, it breaks.

Comment: So don't bother defining the union. And use Marshal class to pick out the fields. Just changing 0 to 4 is not the answer.

Comment: Don't receive a struct by ref. Receive an IntPtr. Then pick out what you need manually.

Comment: So do i have to re-write every function signature that uses DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT as a ref parameter, to use a IntPtr parameter instead? Would that still work with the same C++ functions? Because i cant change the C++ code in any way. Mind you provide an example to be clear? I have added the delegate for the event handler, and a function

Comment: I'd like to see the C++ definition of the callback function

Comment: OK, I've written an answer to flesh out what I mean. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discovered, the marshaler does not like you trying to overlay the array with other fields in your translation of the union. You've suppressed the problem by changing the offset for the array to be 4 rather than 0. But that doesn't help.

Now, since the marshaler won't deal with the union for you, you'll have to do it manually. I would handle this by omitting the non-array members of the union.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT
{
    public DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_CODE eEventCode;
    public DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_TYPE eEventType;
    public int iTime;
    public int iHandle;
    public byte uchAddress;
    public DG_CCTALK_BILL_INFO sBillInfo;
    public int iBillAmount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
    public byte[] uData;
    public IntPtr _private;
}
```

Note that I have removed much of the verbosity of your declaration. I suspect that the type was automatically generated by a tool. But all that verbosity makes it very hard to read.

This will produce the correct layout for the struct, but will leave you with work to do to access the other fields in the union.

So, how can we read those fields? Well, the data is contained in the byte array `uData`, so it is just a matter of reading the values from there. For instance, you could add the following property to the `DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT` struct:

```
public int lData
{
    get { return BitConverter.ToInt32(uData, 0); }
    set { uData = BitConverter.GetBytes(value); }
}

public int iData
{
    get { return BitConverter.ToInt32(uData, 0); }
    set { uData = BitConverter.GetBytes(value); }
}

// etc.
```

Note that the setter will obliterate all the but first 4 bytes of the array, since it overwrites `uData`. I don't know enough about the protocol of the native code to be sure that this is what you want. If it's not what you want, then you might write the setter like this:

```
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), uData, sizeof(int));
```

---

You've now added the C++ side of the interop boundary. The most obvious problem is that your C# delegate appears to have the wrong calling convention. It uses `stdcall` but the C++ code  expects `cdecl`. That's certainly enough to explain a catastrophic crash after your callback returns. You'll need to make sure that your delegate specifies the calling convention.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT_HANDLER(ref DG_CCTALK_APP_EVT pEVT);
```

---

Your translation of `cctalk_app_add_link` is wrong too. It should be:

```
[DllImport("cctalk.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int cctalk_app_add_link(string szPortName);
```

Done like this you can simply pass a string and thus avoid the memory leak that your current implementation has.

Comment: You set the SizeConst variable to 128, but that would only hold the array defined in the uData union, what about the other fields? Shouldn't it actually be bigger?
4 bytes for lData ( or 8, since it is a long?)|
4 bytes for iData
128 bytes for ucArray
4 bytes for cString (or 8 if working on a 64 bit machine since it is a pointer)
4 bytes for pvoid (same as above)

Comment: I have updated my question, with ur answer but it still doesnt work, im really lost here.

Comment: No, a union overlays the members. Hence FieldOffset of 0 for all members as produced by your tool. I'm not really sure what "doesn't work" means here.  You did not do what I said though. Your code has 144 rather than 128.

Comment: All your getters and setters need to work at the beginning of the array. You should read again exactly what a union is.

Comment: What about the IntPtr? How do i manage them? Is my cast correct (Assuming i will be only working on a 32 bit machine)

Comment: Just wondering, cant i just re-write the original C# code i posted, to avoid using a byte[] for the 128 unsigned char in the union, and use lets say two ulong?

Comment: That would be the wrong size. The union is 128 bytes wide. Do you appreciate that with interop, you need to achieve binary compatibility?

Comment: Your cast will work for 32 bit code. But the code in the question doesn't handle the unions properly.

Comment: I'm wondering why you are so hung up on coding all these properties. You don't need any of that to test whether or not you can receive the struct successfully from the C++ callback. Have you done that? I must say I think I have answered the question that you asked which was about a struct translation. If you have other problems caused by code that is not in the question, I'm finding it hard to comment on that which I cannot see. I'd like to help, but you need to do more to work with me.

Comment: I have updated the question, with the setters/getters as you said but i keep getting the same error which is coming from this struct after the event sends it back to the c++ code (without any changes at all, all the event does is printing fields at the moment)

Comment: OK, I've read your update. It's clear that the struct translation is fine. You need to show more of the native side. You still have not shown the native C++ declaration of the callback function. It's frustrating that you have not done so. I asked 6 hours ago! And what exactly is the error?

Comment: Ok i have updated again, the error is written there as well... Im sure its about the struct because other methods invocations seems to be working, if not i will have to re check every other struct and enum definition but they are normal without unions nor complex stuff

Comment: As I suspected. It looks like the calling convention.

Comment: The init method works fine, and after calling the addLink method, an event is rising where i print all the fields of the struct, after that (event code returns) it stops on the c++ side, because no other code is ran after calling addLink

Comment: Do you see anything wrong in the methods or callings? I have been trying to make this work for days and if it wasnt the struct failing i have no idea what could it be.

Comment: Sorry i didnt see your edit, well, i will mark your answer as correct since you gave me the correct struct definition! Thank you very much

Comment: Did you see my update? You need to specify the calling convention on the delegate. It's very plausible that's all that's needed.

Comment: That worked, i would give you 1 million points if i could! Never trust in auto generated code again... thank you :)

Comment: Well, I'm pleased we got there in the end.

Comment: Just wondering, why is that last line a memory leak? Im passing a pointer, shouldnt be the C++ code responsable for it?

Comment: No. The C++ code cannot free it. That has to be done on the heap on which it was allocated. Also, why should the function free it? You the caller might want to re-use it. So it's the caller's task to free it. So yes, it's a leak.

Comment: So it is a leak because im using Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi to convert my C# string to IntPtr, and never calling the free method? Would that work if i call the free method after> Also, do i need to free memory of IntPtr type from returns? For example, a C++ function that returns a char* as IntPtr, i guess i need to free that one as well. Im sorry im learning this is worse than coding in C++ itself :)

Comment: Calls to Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi must be paired with later calls to Marshal.FreeHGlobal as per the docs. As for the other pointers in the struct, the documentation will tell you who needs to free them. However it surely won't be the job of the managed code. That cannot free memory allocated by the native lib. But read the docs.

Answer (score -1):

Check your int and long fields.
I think that C int is 16 bit while C# int is 32:

- If that's true, then iTime, iHandle and iBilAmount are defined as int in both C# and C definitions.
- ***If I'm wrong***, then lData is defined as long in C but int in C# (if that's the problem, then don't forget to fix the offsets of fields that appear after lData).

Comment: Nope. On Windows, C++ int is 32 bits

Comment: It's a union! The offsets are all 0. No fixing required. In C++ on Windows, int and long are 4 bytes wide.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I missed the 128-length array and didn't see that he uses Windows.